# Issue with Morris Line

Tags: php, morris.js

I am trying to show 2 lines in the chart itself on top/ overlapping one another but it is shown side by side. I have some doubts whether it is actually caused by the repeating x axis points. However, i am unsure on how to join them together as my x axis isn't reflecting time/date etc. Also another issue seems to be that on the top of the chart there are some data points present there. Data points are taken from my database which i have check that there is no stray data. Do forgive me if i make any mistake as i am still new in morris.JS. Query is also working fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Graph:[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSaoz.jpg)

What i wanted: [Lines are stacked/overlapping each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMQkr.png)

Here is the process on how i get the data to show on the graph:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $chart_data .= "{ time:".$row["time_spent"].", finger:'".$row["finger"]."'},  ";
       
}

$chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultR))
{
    $chart_dataR .= "{ timeR:".$row["time_spent"].", finger:'".$row["finger"]."'},  ";
       
}

$chart_dataR = substr($chart_dataR, 0, -2);
```

Here are my code for the morris script:

```
Morris.Line({
 element : 'chart',
 data:[<?php echo $chart_data, $chart_dataR;?> ],
 xkey:'finger',
 ykeys:['time', 'timeR'],
 labels:['Time Spent (in sec)'],
 pointFillColors: ['#00ff00'],
 lineColors: ['#000000', '#0AAEF3'],
 pointSize: 7,
 lineWidth: 4,
 hideHover:'auto',
 parseTime:false, 

});
```